# How to include the assembly name in the service type declaration in web.config in wcf?

Tags: wcf

I am implementing this from a WCF book. I read the following from the book:

The website config file (web.config) typically lists the types you want to expose as services. **You need to use fully qualified type names, including the assembly name if the service type comes from an unreferenced assembly:**

```
< system.serviceModel > 
    < services > 
        < service name = "MyNamespace.MyService" > ... </ service > 
    </ services > 
</ system.serviceModel >
```

Using this, I have written the following in web.config in my Service project:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="MyService.svc" service="Service"/>
        <add relativeAddress="MyAssemblyService.svc" service="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>
      <service name="Service">
      </service>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
      </service>
    </services>
```

Here, if I reference the Service Assembly in my WCF Service project, I can access the service, but if I leave out the reference to Service Assembly, I get the following error:

> The type 'WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1', provided as the Service
>   attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the
>   configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.

I have searched a lot to find, how to specify the full qualified service name in the "name" attribute including the assembly, but it seems either I am not using the right search keywords or we can't specify the assembly name in "name" attribute.

Can we specify the assembly name inside the "name" attribute?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Of course you need to reference the assembly if the service type is in there.

Comment: See the line I have made bold. It says, you can leave out the assembly reference and for doing that, you need to mention the fully qualified name of the service type including its assembly. This seems intuitively possible to me and to test the same, I am doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the bold, I missed that sentence. :) Try "WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1, YourLibraryAssembly" - this is usally the format. No idea if it works though.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need the fully qualified name, and the assembly in the GAC
Here is a hint how to get the fully qualified name:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2exyydhb.aspx

Here is the tutorial for installing the assembly in the GAC:
http://net-informations.com/faq/framework/add-remove-assembly